# List index out of range python after appending to the list

Tags: python

I wanted to add each proxy by splitting it at the colon and then add to a list. One thing i need to do is then add back the colon to the end of the first 3 of 4 list indexes, i cannot do this because while testing to make sure it compiles i get this error, `lists index out of range.` So i thought okay maybe they are all being appended into one string in the list so i did a print statement and i see this, `[['fa8tUVQ.usa.unknownproxies.com', '10000', 'mferraro2304', 'o3VXtvjHpWr4\n']]` is there a chance that the double bracket is messing it up? if so how can i remove this and then proceed to re add the colons? here is my code:

```
for lines in ordered_proxies:
    pvar = lines.split(':')  # rotating proxy or host
    pvars.append(pvar)
print(pvars)
PROXY_HOST = pvars[0]
PROXY_PORT = pvars[1]
PROXY_USER = pvars[2]
PROXY_PASS = pvars[3]

manifest_json = """
{
"version": "1.0.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Chrome Proxy",
"permissions": [
"proxy",
"tabs",
"unlimitedStorage",
"storage",
"<all_urls>",
"webRequest",
"webRequestBlocking"
],
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
  "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
 }
 """
background_js = """
var config = {
mode: "fixed_servers",
rules: {
singleProxy: {
   scheme: "http",
   host: "%s",
   port: parseInt(%s)
   },
   bypassList: ["localhost"]
   }
};
chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
    authCredentials: {
    username: "%s",
    password: "%s"
    }
    };
    }

    chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
          callbackFn,
          {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
          ['blocking']
);
""" % (PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASS)
get_chromedriver()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that pvars is a list, and I will sasume that ordered_proxies is some sort of collection with multiple lines, like a file.  Here is what you are doing:

You are looping over the lines of ordered_proxies.  You are splitting each line.  The function "split" returns a list, which you are appending to pvars.  So when your loop is finished, pvars is a complicated data structure: it's a list of lists.

pvars[0] is the list of strings you got when you split the first line of ordered_proxies.  The length of pvars[0] is equal to the number of colon-separated items in the first line.

pvars[1] is the list of strings you got when you split the second line of ordered_proxies.

The length of pvars is the number of lines in ordered_proxies.

The print statement is telling you that pvars is a list (that's what the outer set of square brackets mean) containing ONE list (delimited by the inner set of square brackets).  The double square brackets is not "messing up" anything; it's telling you that the length of pvars is 1 and that its only element is a four-item list.

You get an error when you try to access the second element in pvars, pvars[1], since pvars doesn't have a second element.

I can't understand what you're trying to do, but I can see why your code isn't working.

Comment: i wanted to split the parts of the proxy up so i can then assign them each to variables which then will be used to implement the proxies into a selenium web driver. the reason im doing it this way is because im pulling each proxy from a text file and assigning different proxies to each browser i create.

Comment: I think you probably need to create each browser INSIDE the for loop, so you will get one browser for each line in the file.  The variable pvar already contains the items from splitting the line, which is all you need.  Putting each pvar into a longer pvars list isn't necessary.